# attribute <p></p> doesn't do a line-break while working with flexible boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

I am designing a flexible website composed of 5 elements (4 `<div>` elements and 1 `<iframe>`), where everything works fine up until the moment when I add `<p></p>` element which doesn't want to give me a line-break. I tried also including `display:block;` in the CSS and tried to style in many different ways but nothing made any difference; mostly it just displaces all website.

Thanks for any help!

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><!--<!doctype html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"-->
<html>
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css"> 

    body{width:100%;
        -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        margin: 0px auto;
        padding: 0px;
        display: -webkit-box;}
    div,iframe{border:1px solid black;
                -webkit-box-flex:1;
                display: -webkit-box;}
        div#pas1{height: 33.33vh;
            -webkit-box-pack: center;
            -webkit-box-align: end;}
        div#pas2{-webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
                    height: 33.33vh;}
        div#a{width: 33.33vw;
            -webkit-box-pack: end;
            -webkit-box-align: center;
            border:1px solid black;} 
        div#iframe{width:33.33vw;
                max-width:500px;}
        div#b{width: 33.33vw;
            -webkit-box-pack: start;
            -webkit-box-align: center;} 
        div#pas3{height: 33.33vh;
            -webkit-box-pack: start;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

        <div id="pas1">
        </div>
        <div id="pas2">
            <div id="a"><p><a target="jednotka">a</a></p>
                        <p><a target="jednotka">b</a></p>
                        <p><a target="jednotka">c</a></p></div>
            <div id="iframe"><iframe name="jednotka" ></iframe></div>
            <div id="b"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="pas3">
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Why are you using paragraphs as spacers...that's not what they are for.? Use margins...

Comment: Also, you are using a **very** old flexbox syntax.

Comment: can you add a fiddle with your whole markup and css

Comment: ...and `<p>` is not an *attribute*...it's an **element**.

Comment: add a property `flex-wrap: wrap` to the flex container

Answer (score 0):

So you want line break for the p element inside the div id #a.you can try this 
div#a p{width:100%; display:inline-block;} check the css part I also added some additional css for styling but that display:inline-block; and width is the reason for the line-break.
The css you set in side div#a {-webkit-box-pack: end;} is the reason text start at the of the div#a 
 [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2jp20meu/3/)

```css
        body {
      width: 100%;
      -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
      margin: 0px auto;
      padding: 0px;
      display: -webkit-box;
    }
    
    div, 
    iframe {
      border: 1px solid black;
      -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      display: -webkit-box;
    }
    
    div#pas1 {
      height: 33.33vh;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -webkit-box-align: end;
    }
    
    div#pas2 {
      -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
      height: 33.33vh;
    }
    
    div#a {
      width: 33.33vw;
      -webkit-box-pack: end;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    div#iframe {
      width: 33.33vw;
      max-width: 500px;
    }
    
    div#b {
      width: 33.33vw;
      -webkit-box-pack: start;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
    }
    
    div#pas3 {
      height: 33.33vh;
      -webkit-box-pack: start;
    }
    
    #a p {
      width:100%;
      display:inline-block;
   margin:0;
    
      }
    #a p a{
      text-decoration:none;
      margin:5px 0px;   
        font-size:18px;}
```

```html
    <div id="pas1">
</div>
<div id="pas2">
  <div id="a">
    <p><a href="#" target="jednotka">a</a></p>
    <p><a href="#" target="jednotka">b</a></p>
    <p><a href="#" target="jednotka">c</a></p>
  </div>
  <div id="iframe">
    <iframe  src="http://www.w3schools.com"
    name="jednotka"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div id="b"></div>
</div>
<div id="pas3">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very very much Mostafa, that is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Using the new `flexbox` specification standard:
[one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) & [two](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex).

https://jsfiddle.net/fz5vpten/

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0;}
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: center;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
}

iframe {width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0;}

div#pas1 {
  height: 33.33vh;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

div#pas2 {
  height: 33.33vh;
  flex-direction: row;
}

div#a {
  width: 33.33vw;
  border: 1px solid black;
  
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

div#iframe {
  width: 33.33vw;
  max-width: 500px;
}

div#b {
  width: 33.33vw;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

div#pas3 {
  height: 33.33vh;
  justify-content: start;
}
```

```html
<div id="pas1">
</div>

<div id="pas2">

  <div id="a">
    <p><a target="jednotka">a</a></p>
    <p><a target="jednotka">b</a></p>
    <p><a target="jednotka">c</a></p>
  </div>
  
  <div id="iframe">
    <iframe name="jednotka"></iframe>
  </div>
  
  <div id="b">
  </div>
  
</div>

<div id="pas3">
</div>
```